# Google tag analytics4 is not firing on clicking search button under dev,qa environments in tealium

Tags: tealium

Google tag analytics4 should fire under 2 conditions
1)All page views
2)when search button is entered

**Load rule mentioned is**
-All pages(as dom.domain is constant for every page, i have set "dom.domain EQUALS_IGNORE_CASE ecommerce.tealiumdemo.com" and so it is firing for all pages)

**Event rule mentioned is**

*

```
Configuration
Name
*Required
 search event
​
Notes
​
Scope
After Load Rules
​
Tracking Event
Link
​
Publish Locations
Dev
QA
Prod
Event Triggers
Click
Element Selector
#search
​
Target a specific element by entering its ID, class, or another valid selector.
Trigger Frequency
Always
​
Select to trigger this event always or once.
Event Trigger Variables
Set
Tealium Event To Text search
```

- 

it is how I have configured it so please help me change anything that will make this google analytics tag4 fire on search event
​

i have tried multiple times changing each option present in configuration and changed load rule condition from or to and, and viceversa but none have worked.....so i want a solution